# How to sort a 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the names for 5 students and their grades for 3 subjects and I have calculated their average for the 3 courses. But then I need to sort them with their data(name, grades for the 3 courses and average) from the one with the highest average to the lowest.
can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code? 
here is my code ...

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void read(string names[],double grades[][4],int n);
void average(double grades[][4], int n);
void sort(string names[],double grades[][4], int n);
int main()
{
    string names[5]; double grades[5][4];
    cout<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision (2);
    cout<<" please enter the names and grades(math,phy,cpp) for 5 students\n";
    read(names,grades,5);
    average(grades,5);
    sort(names,grades,5);
    for(int rows=0; rows<5; rows++)
    {
        cout<<names[rows]<<"\t";
        for( int col=0; col<4; col++)
        {
            cout<<grades[rows][col]<<"\t";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }







    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void read(string names[],double grades[][4],int n)
{
    for(int rows=0; rows<n; rows++)
    {
            cin>>names[rows];
        for( int col=0; col<3; col++)
        { 
            cin>>grades[rows][col];
        }
    }
    system("cls");
}
void average(double grades[][4], int n)
{
    double sum;
    for(int rows=0; rows<n; rows++)
    {
        sum=0.0;
        for(int col=0; col<3;col++)
        {
            sum=sum+grades[rows][col];
        }
        grades[rows][3]=sum/3;
    }
}

void sort(string names[],double grades[][4], int n)
{
    double temp;int end=n;string swap_names;


    for(int rows=0; rows<end; rows++)
    {
        if(grades[rows][3]> grades[rows+1][3])
        {
            for(int col=0; col<4;col++)
            {
                temp=grades[rows+1][col];
                grades[rows+1][col]=grades[rows][col];
                grades[rows][col]=temp;
            }
            swap_names=names[rows+1];
            names[rows+1]=names[rows];
            names[rows]=swap_names;
        }
    }


}
```

thanks.

Comment: One suggestion:  Create a class for the student containing their name, grades and averages. Then store those objects in a vector.  Then use `std::sort()` with a custom function or callable object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `sort()` function. Bubble sort is a **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** sort, where as your `sort()` only takes **O(n)** time which is in correct.

Try this corrected code of `sort()`,

```
void sort(string names[],double grades[][4], int n)
{
    double temp;
    int end=n;
    string swap_names;
    for(int rows1=0; rows1<end; rows1++)
    {

      for(int rows2=0; rows2<end; rows2++)
      {
        if(grades[rows1][3] < grades[rows2][3])
        {
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            {
                temp=grades[rows1][i];
                grades[rows1][i]=grades[rows2][i];
                grades[rows2][i]=temp;
            }
            swap_names=names[rows1];
            names[rows1]=names[rows2];
            names[rows2]=swap_names;
        }
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sort algorithm is not yet complete. It is one iteration of the so called Bubble sort algorithm, see [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) for more details. Bubble sort does however have quite a bad performance, if your database is big, then you should really consider using a sort from a library as suggested in one of the comments.